# Problem setting up wlan(adhoc network) on ubuntu

Tags: networking

I need help creating a wlan on a laptop running ubuntu so that I can connect my other laptop to it via the network. 
I went to the network settings pane and created an adhoc network, however when I try to connect the other laptop, It says it cannot connect to the network.

Comment: Do you want to setup an ad hoc WiFi access point in one Ubuntu computer so that another computer can access it?

Comment: Yes please, I created some but the other computer sees it but is unable to connect to it.

Comment: Please edit the original question and add details of what you have done.

Comment: Okay...........  Thanks.